# Should I use IEmailSender?

Tags: asp.net-core, interface, asp.net-identity

I'm using AspNetCore.Identity at my project, so I write a EmailSender class that implements this interface.

Everything is working fine.

But this description about `IEmailSender` took my attention:

> **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services.IEmailSender**
>    This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infraestructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases

[image]

If it isn't intended to be used directly in my code, what should I use?
My application also send emails in other parts, not only for Identity.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think you need to use `IEmailSender`. In fact, based on my experience, to some degrees I think you shouldn't use it:

1. In .NET 5.0, `IEmailSender` is in the package `ASP.NET Core Identity.UI`, with the [default implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/UI/src/Areas/Identity/Services/EmailSender.cs) injected in DI that doesn't do anything. It's perfectly fine if you want to use the default UI provided by the framework. But if you don't like to use those default pages and just want to use the core of the Identity framework, including the whole package just to get `IEmailSender` interface seems overkill to me. Not to mention there is [an annoying bug](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/16482) when using Identity UI at this moment.
2. It doesn't add any value. I would have been persuaded if the framework could automatically scan my concrete implementation and use that instead to send out emails. But that's not the case. You would have to inject your email sender through DI by `services.AddSingleton<>()` yourself and use it via constructor injection where you want to send emails.
3. `IEmailSender.SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string htmlMessage)` method is pretty basic. Most of the time you even would have to create your own razor library to generate the HTML message yourself. In my case (using SendGrid v9.22 with dynamic template), I would need to not only pass the HTML message, but also the template data (for setting the placeholder in my SendGrid template via `msg.SetTemplateData()`). The basic `SendEmailAsync()` just doesn't have extra parameters for me to send additional data when sending the email.

#### Conclusion:

If you see yourself that you won't switch to email provider for a project, you might as well just create a concrete email sender that fits you well, and inject that into DI directly.

If you see there might be a time when your project will switch email provider, having a basic and simple interface, like `IEmailSender`, makes sense.

Comment: Can you give an example how you use your own Methods to deliver E-Mail via ASP.NET Identity without the use of `IEmailSender`? It seems my own searches have been fruitless and as you said. `SendEmailAsync` is very bare. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @Kyte: I haven't worked with .NET 5 for a while and I am just trying to refresh my memory here. Like what I said at point #1 and 2, the default implementation from ASP.NET Core for `IEmailSender` basically does nothing. So if you don't use that and create your own (you can call it the same name if you want) and have a method like `SendEmailAsync(string sendTo, string subject, string htmlMessage, string[] bccList, string[] ccList)`, you can create your own implementation of it. And at the end of the day, the only thing you need to do is to register your own pair as singleton with the DI.

Comment: Just to be clear: doing so above doesn't automatically send the email for you. You would have to declare your own email sender interface as private readonly variable, declare it as one of the constructor parameters and call your send email method wherever you want to send email.

Comment: Yes, that's what i ended up with as well. ASP.Net Identity is a lot of intransparent magic and handwaving for me so i assumed that by declaring a `IEmailSender` Singleton in a DI it would be injected automatically into whatever functionality is behind everything and automatically called upon calling `UserManager.CreateAsync()` which is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely should, as the `IEmailSender` is the best available option offered by the framework to send email messages, especially if you have to deal with ASP.NET Identity stuff (*account confirmation*, *password recovery* and so on).

However, in order to use it properly, you should implement it using one of the many third-party services (and their corresponding .NET NuGet packages), as suggested in this [official post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio).

If you need further instruction to setup these email sender provider, you can take a look at these implementation guides that I wrote on my blog (*DISCLAIMER: I'm not affiliated with any of them*):

- [.NET Core General Purpose SMTP implementation using MailKit](https://www.ryadel.com/en/asp-net-core-send-email-messages-smtp-mailkit/)
- [.NET Core IEmailSender implementation using Twilio SendGrid API](https://www.ryadel.com/en/asp-net-core-send-email-messages-sendgrid-api/)
- [.NET Core IEmailSender implementation using SendInBlue API](https://www.ryadel.com/en/asp-net-core-sendinblue-send-email-messages-smtp/)

The fact that the API could get removed in the future shouldn't bother you at all, since all of these third-party packages have their own API: you'll be able to use them even without the [IEmailSender](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.ui.services.iemailsender) interface (as a matter of fact, you already can).

Comment: I disagree, as David points out, the IEmailSender signature is very basic and does not allow you to pass enough information.