Can I combine ASP.NET Core Identity with JWTs?
I'm new to the .NET world and I would like to setup authentication in my Web API with JWTs.
I saw that ASP.NET Core Identity can scaffold the functionality for auth by mapping some endpoints (app.MapIdentityApi<User>();). However, I'd like to use JWTs instead of simple text string bearer tokens (which comes by default).
I'm trying to set this all up in a Modular Monolith. So far, here's my setup:
Program.cs of the "host" web app:
using ...;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddUserModuleServices(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.MapIdentityApi<User>();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

Then, in my User Module I have the following service collection extension:
using ...;

namespace ...;

public static class UserModuleServiceExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddUserModuleServices(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        ConfigurationManager config)
    {
        string? connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("UsersConnectionString");
        services.AddDbContext<UserDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(connectionString));
        
        // Configure identity
        services.AddIdentityCore<User>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        
        // Configure JWT Authentication
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    
                ValidIssuer = config["JwtSettings:Issuer"],
                ValidAudience = config["JwtSettings:Audience"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config["JwtSettings:Key"]!))
            };
        });
        
        return services;
    }
}

However, I'm not able to run this app. I get the error:

Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IEmailSender`1[namespace...]' has been registered.

Any tips? What am I missing? As mentioned earlier, I'm new to .NET Core so I'm feeling a bit lost here.

The error looks unrelated to JWT - it looks like you don't have an email sender configured: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64409815/1064169

Shouldn't that come out of the box with ASP.NET Core Identity? It wasn't complaining until I changed services.AddIdentityCore... .AddApiEndpoints() to .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

AddIdentityCore doesn't contain enough services for app.MapIdentityApi<User>();.
Generally, we use following for MapIdentiyApi:
services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<User>()
            ....

or you could also add extra services like below:
services.AddIdentityCore<User>()
    .AddApiEndpoints()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

Just note that AddIdentityCore doesn't contains any authentication scheme. But AddIdentityApiEndpoints already contains cookie scheme and jwt sheme. cookie or jwt will both work without extra configuration.
But of course, you could specify configure the default scheme as you wish
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
...


Hey! Thanks for your reply. I managed to fix it by adding services.AddIdentityCore<User>()             .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserDbContext>()             .AddDefaultTokenProviders()             .AddApiEndpoints();. I was missing .AddApiEndpoints(). I'm now curious though, as to what you mean with JWTs without extra config. You still need some kind of service that will issue the tokens, right? Or am I missing something? I saw that there's a command "dotnet user-jwts" but I'm not sure if it's actually a good setup. Also, are you sure you don't mean plain text tokens rather than JWT?

@nicolascanala I mean with the MapIdentityApi you get some endpoints. Such as "signin" you can get access token, right? You can access protected controler with this token without using addauthentication   if you use AddIdentityApiEndpoints instead of AddIdentityCore

You also get the endpoints by using AddIdentityCore along with .AddApiEndpoints()! The token that it uses by default is a Bearer, plain text token though, not a JWT. I guess I'll need a service that issues the JWT and hook into the default registration endpoint to return that instead. As mentioned, pretty new to .NET (but not backend dev) so I'm really not sure of what I'm talking about in the .NET context lol. Docs seem pretty vague and push you to use external identity providers to authenticate your APIs for some reason... Thank you!
